# How to apply new wireless settings on an OpenWRT router without rebooting it?

Tags: openwrt

After I manually edit the:

```
vi /etc/config/wireless
```

file, what should I do to apply the modifications? Until this day I rebooted the router, but aren't there any better solutions? (and no, www is disabled on the router)

Answer (score 5):

There is special `wifi` command. There is a lot of references but I didn't find any standalone manual for it.

```
Usage: /sbin/wifi [down|detect|reload|status]
```

To apply wireless settings use

```
wifi reload
```

Answer (score 5):

```
/etc/init.d/network reload
```

source: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/netifd

Comment: No, what you are saying here is for `/etc/config/network`, not for `/etc/config/wireless`

Comment: @huangzonghao When you run `/etc/init.d/network reload` it calls `/sbin/wifi reload_legacy` in the `reload_service` part of the script so it does reload the wireless settings.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers worked for me. The only one that works fine, run:

```
/sbin/wifi
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to reboot the router so that new wireless changes can be applied to the wireless portion of the router.
Alternatively, you can use:

```
wifi down
wifi up
```